# Selecting 1 Instance of a Client's family in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What I need to return from the query is a list of Heads of Households who have visited in the past year and all of their relatives. Everyone is in the Client table which is joined to the other tables when queried.

The problem is that the query returns a "set" of Family members for each unique DateVisited. I'm hoping to get a set of results that looks like this (I omitted some columns for clarity):

```
Head of household                Relative/child
----------------------------     ---------------------
John Smith -                     Katie Smith
John Smith                       Joe Smith
Tim Jones                        Mike Jones
Tim Jones                        Sally Jones
Kevin Barnett                    Corey Barnett
Kevin Barnett                    Cara Barnett
Kevin Barnett                    Austin Barnett




SELECT f.HeadOfHouseholdID,
  CONCAT( c.lastname,  ', ', c.firstname ) AS  'HName',
  v.Datevisited, f.RelationshipID, c2.ClientID,
  CONCAT( c2.lastname,  ', ', c2.firstname ) AS  'Relative Name'
FROM client c
INNER JOIN clientfamily f ON c.ClientID = f.HeadOfHouseholdID
JOIN visits v ON c.clientid = v.clientID
JOIN client c2 ON c2.clientid = f.relativeID
WHERE v.datevisited BETWEEN CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND CURDATE( )
```

![Query Results][1]

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server.  SQLServer is easier as you can use a recursive CTE and knock this off in one query.  mysql requires a temp table.

Comment: @Hogan To concatenate in SQL Server, [one just uses +](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx), so I expect this is MySQL.

Comment: The database is MySQL.


    SELECT headofhouseholdid, CONCAT( c.lastname,  ', ', c.firstname ) AS  'HName', v.datevisited, f.relationshipid, c2.clientid, CONCAT( c2.lastname,  ', ', c2.firstname ) AS  'Relative Name'
    FROM client c
    INNER JOIN clientfamily f ON c.clientid = f.headofhouseholdid
    JOIN (
    
    SELECT ClientID, MAX( DateVisited ) AS  'DateVisited'
    FROM Visits
    GROUP BY ClientID
    )v ON c.clientid = v.clientid
    JOIN client c2 ON c2.clientid = f.relativeid
    WHERE v.datevisited
    BETWEEN CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND CURDATE( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker figured it out:

```
SELECT f.HeadOfHouseholdID 'HOHID',
    CONCAT( c.Lastname, ', ', c.FirstName ) AS 'Head of Household',
    c.PhoneNumber AS 'HOH Phone',
    f.RelativeID,
    CONCAT( C2.Lastname, ', ', C2.FirstName ) AS 'Relative',
    Relationship.Description AS 'Relation',
    C2.PhoneNumber AS 'Relative Phone', C2.DOB,
    (
            (
            DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y' ) - DATE_FORMAT( C2.DOB, '%Y' )
            ) -
            ( DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '00-%m-%d' ) < DATE_FORMAT( C2.DOB, '00-%m-%d' ) )
    ) AS Age
    FROM client c
    INNER JOIN clientfamily f ON c.clientid = f.headofhouseholdid
    JOIN (
            SELECT ClientID, MAX( DateVisited ) AS 'DateVisited'
            FROM Visits
            GROUP BY ClientID
    ) v ON c.clientid = v.clientid
    JOIN client c2 ON c2.clientid = f.relativeid
    JOIN Relationship ON f.RelationshipID = Relationship.RelationshipID
    WHERE v.datevisited
            BETWEEN CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
            AND CURDATE( )
```